# WebRtc,onaddstream,receive,stream,no show?

Tags: webrtc

I met with difficulties.

```
var onaddstream = function(event){
    var video = $("#chat_dialogForOne video[name='remote']")[0];
    var remoteStream = event.stream;
    video.srcObject = remoteStream;
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
        video.play();
    };
}
```

[image]

```
$("#chat_dialogForOne button[name='openVideo']").on("click",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).data("use",$(this).data("use") ? false : true);
    if($(this).data("use")){//开启视频语音聊天
        rtc.openVideoAudioLocal(function(localStream){//创建本地视频流,绑定到控件上
            var video = $("#chat_dialogForOne video[name='video']")[0]; //获取到展现视频的标签
            video.srcObject=localStream;
            video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
                video.play();
            };
            rtc.openVideoAudioLocal(function(remoteStream){
                rtc.sendAddStream(remoteStream);
            },true,true);
        },true,false);//为了防止自己能听到自己发出的声音,只启动视频,不启动音频
        $(this).find(" > span").html("结束视频");
        $("#chat_dialogForOne button[name='openAudio']").hide();
    }else{//关闭视频语音聊天
        // closeRemoteChannelStream([oneWebRtc]);
        // closeLocalStream();
        // resetVideoButton();
    }
});
```

[image]

images 2,Successful display of local

images 1,Failure Display Remote

onaddstream,Received the remote stream, it does not show.to video

I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was a mistake of mine. I made a very slight mistake, which resulted in a new PC object being recreated after receiving the offer. Although the remote received the video stream object, the channel had been replaced.